# Анимация не проигрывается повторно android

Tags: android, android-animation

Есть анимация и я хочу что бы она проигрывалась каждый раз по нажатию на кнопку, но она проигрывается только при первом нажатии. Что я делаю неправильно?

```
mButtonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mButtonNext.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.button_next_anim));
        }
});
```

anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="100"
    android:duration="100"
    />

</set>
```

my_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBackgroundGrey"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/header_button_shape_baground"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<util.CustomViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button_next_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_next_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_marginRight"
        android:background="@drawable/button_next_word_rectangle"
        android:text="СЛЕДУЮЩЕЕ СЛОВО"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_next_font_size"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontBlue"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: вы хотите, чтобы кнопка сдвигалась на 100 вправо каждый раз, когда вы на нее нажимаете?

Comment: @metalurgus да.  но она это делает только при первом нажатии!

Comment: Вы, значит, просто не знаете, как работает анимация. Попробуйте нажать на то место, где была кнопка до первой анимации.

Comment: @metalurgus в смысле "на то место" - типа в одну и туже точку жать каждый раз?

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы кнопка при каждом нажатии так и уползала на 100 каждый раз до конца экрана или она все же должна в конце анимации вернуться, а при следующем нажатии сдвинуться на 100 опять от первоначального положения.

Comment: @pavlofff да, она должна отползать на 100 вправо и после этого возвращаться в исходной положение и при следующих нажатиях это должно повторяться.

Comment: Ну продолжите анимацию такое же движение назад

Comment: @pavlofff добавил еще один блок     <translate
        android:fromXDelta="100"
        android:toXDelta="0"
        /> - но ничего

Answer (score 1):

metalurgus намекает Вам, что вы забыли указать проценты:

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:duration="100"
    />
```

Попробуйте после воспроизведения анимации чистить её

```
mButtonNext.clearAnimation();
```

Comment: нет, не на это я намекаю)) На то, что кнопка не передвигается на 100 пикселей вправо при анимации. Только ее изображеие

Comment: =) Эх, опять я не так понял

Comment: если в обработчик добавить  строку mButtonNext.clearAnimation();
то анимация вобще не проигрывается, я так понял что она просто не успевает!

Comment: добавив проценты ничего не изменилось! может нужно привести дополнительный код, ну там разметки или активити?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, в чем у вас ошибка. У меня в таком варианте все отлично работает - при нажатии кнопка смещается вправо, возвращается назад. При следующем нажатии все повторяется:

```
    animButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.animation);
            v.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    });
```

**res/anim/animation.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="100"
    android:duration="100" />
```

Comment: т.е вы в анимации не возвращаете на исходную  позицию и тем не менее у вас все работает? Что может влиять на анимацию в моем приложении?

Comment: проверил в тестовой активити - тоже все работает, видать причина в моей разметке. на понятно только что именно, и почему все таки первый раз она срабатывает, а потом нет!